# Drag and drop in .NET Core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, drag-and-drop

We have a web application developed with **ASP.NET Core 2.2**. We want to provide customisable widgets for displaying data and think drag and drop would be a nice way of presenting this. We currently use *Kendo UI* controls for many of our UI controls but the drag and drop functionality looks very basic.

Our UI stack looks like this:

- ASP.NET Core 2.2
- Kendo UI controls for ASP.NET Core
- Bootstrap 4

Many of the JS frameworks use Bootstrap 3 panels to implement drag and drop, but panels have been discontinued in Bootstrap 4 (and replaced by cards).

What are others using to implement drag and drop in ASP.NET Core web applications?

Comment: You can use https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc I was referring to drag & dropping widgets and data not upload files